# Simple code to obtain n-th number of Fibonnaci

Tags: c++

I am just trying to produce an efficient piece of code to obtain the n-th number of a Fibonacci sequence and am using the code below to do this. But, I get the error `Expression: vector subscript out of range` and don't know why it happens.

```
int Fib(int n)
{
    vector<int> output;
    output.reserve(n);
    output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
    for(int i = 2; i <=n; ++i)
    {
        output.push_back(output[i-1]+ output[i-2]);
    }
return output[n];
}
```

Comment: `output.reserve(n+1)` should not hurt.

Comment: Why not do it in constant time? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19892721/382471

Comment: Or let your compiler generate it http://goo.gl/jfZXKY Of course this will only work if you know which step of the Fibonacco series you want at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code returns an invalid value for Fib(0) (1 instead of 0) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.

The following code fixes this issue and the vector initialization:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    vector<int> output;
    output.resize(n+1);
    output.clear();
    output.push_back(0);
    output.push_back(1);

    for (int i=2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        output.push_back(output[i-1] + output[i-2]);
    }

    return output[n];
}
```

Any way there's even a better implementation which doesn't require the use of vectors:

```
int fib(int n) 
{
    if ( n == 0 || n == 1 ) 
        return n;

    int fib1 = 0; 
    int fib2 = 1;
    int fib = 0;

    for ( int i = 2; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        fib = fib1 + fib2;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = fib;
    }

    return fib;
}
```

Comment: "Way better" if you want that and only that number, whereas a vector lets you save your work. Though I suppose his is currently written that way, but perhaps it won't always be? Just a comment.

Comment: I understand your point, but the question is "code to obtain the n-th number of a Fibonacci " .. not the whole sequence

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after writing that... Figured I'd leave it there in case it changes into that later.

Comment: switching to `resize` is not sufficient to fix this, since there are `push_back`s performed.

Comment: You are right, I forgot the .clear() and the first two elements

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::reserve` is only a performance hint for the container to preallocate storage for data; it does not actually fill the vector with `n` elements. So, when you try to access the elements like `output[0] = 1`, you are accessing non-existing elements.

You can simply switch to `std::vector::resize`, which does what you want. Note that after thas `std::vector::push_back` makes the algorithm wrong, you should do

```
output[n] = output[n-1] + output[n-2];
```

By the way, this method is not very efficient, at least due to needless memory allocation. Something like this should be faster:

```
int Fib(int n)
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int t = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
output.reserve(n);
```

does not add elements to the vector - it merely reserves space in memory for that amount of items. It does not populate the vector with anything - you can verify this by calling `size()` on the vector which will return zero. Therefore here

```
output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
```

you are attempting to **modify** values at specific indices - but there is nothing at these indices and your indices exceed the vector array bounds (as the message tells you). You should actually populate the vector before you try reading from or writing to specific indices.

In your case simply adding

```
output.push_back(1);
output.push_back(2);
```

prior to your loop will resolve this problem (alternatively use `resize` as other answers suggest).

Answer (score 1):

[Reserving != Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

You're not inserting default-constructed elements that you can later access with the subscript `operator[]`, but rather hinting to allocate uninitialized memory which only affects the **capacity** and not the **size** of the container. Accessing elements that way is therefore invalid.

Even these pre-loop lines are invalid

```
output.reserve(n);
output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
```

You should rather use `resize()` and be aware that `push_back` will then increase the vector's dimensions (so either use `push_back`s all the way in your code or do `resize()` and use the subscript access).

```
int Fib(int n)
{ // Lacks error checking if n < 2
  vector<int> output;
  output.resize(n);
  output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
  for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
  {
    output[i] = output[i - 1] + output[i - 2];
  }
  return output[n-1];
}
```

*Extra-tips*:

- If you're just interested in the `n-th` Fibonacci number you don't need a full-fledged history with a vector, you can just cache the last two numbers in the sequence
- For large `n` this approach won't probably work, a smarter approach that runs in logarithmic time (although you still have to do some easy matrix multiplication) could be the following [[Linear recurrence relations]](http://marcodiiga.github.io/linear-recurrence-relations/)

Answer (score 1):

```
int fib()
{
cout<<"Enter the term";
cin>>n;
int f=0,f1=1,f2=0;
for(i=1;i!=n;i++)
{
f=f1+f2;
f1=f2;
f2=f;
}
if(i==n)
cout<<n<<"'th term is"<<f;
}
```

Is it simple enough correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since you reserve a space for `n` variables, you vector can be indexed up to `n-1`, whereas you return `output[n]`, thereby resulting in the error: `vector subscript out of range`. To have space for the last variable you should use `reserve(n+1)`. However, note that this will be the `n+1` fibonacci number.

Also, `vector.reserve()` allocates memory to the vector without initialising it. So you can't access elements such as `output[0]`. Instead you should either `push_back` the values at index 0 and 1 (along with other values), or use `vector.resize()` and then access all elements by index instead of using `push_back`.

For a explanation on the difference between `resize` and `reserve`, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve) SO thread.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) only increases the capacity (ie. allocated space) for the vector - it doesn't actually increase the size (ie. number of items) of the vector.

So :

```
output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
```

is not legal, since you're trying to access the first two items in a vector of size 0.

Instead, do :

```
output.push_back(1);
output.push_back(2); // this should probably push back 1 though, if you want the Fibonacci sequence
```

Additionally, you're trying to add one too many item into the vector, so change the loop to :

```
for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
```

(ie. use `<` instead of `<=`).

You'll also have to modify the return statement accordingly :

```
return output[n - 1];
```

Comment: With this F(0) will result in an out of boundaries access --> output[-1]

Comment: @redobot : there's no such thing as a 0-th Fibonacci number, so that call would not be valid.

Comment: The mathematical definition of the fibonaccie series starts in 0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: @redobot : it can either start with index 0 or 1 (as indicated in your supporting link), but in both those cases, you would still call it the 1st, not the 0th.

Comment: Yes, that's right. In that case it would be better to have code that supports both cases :)

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> output;
        output.resize(n+1); // resize not reserv  & n+1 because the <=n
        output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            output[i]=(output[i - 1] + output[i - 2]); // indexing not push_back
        }
```

BTW if you really want to use vectors which not seems a best option you should better do something like :

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> output;
output.resize(n+1);
output[0] = 1; output[1] = 2;
const auto end_of_output(std::end(output));
for (auto& it = std::begin(output) + 2; it < end_of_output; ++it){
    *it = *(it - 1) + *(it - 2);
}
```