# Is it possible to calculate isFibonacci() in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

It is possible to create a fast "give n-th fibonacci number" function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037472/can-a-fibonacci-function-be-written-to-execute-in-o1-time). Is there a way to write a `isFibonacci(int i)` function that perform in O(1)?

I could precalculate values. But the calculation  last O(n) and I cant do it for big numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number is Fibonacci if and only if one or both of (5*n<sup>2</sup> + 4) or (5*n<sup>2</sup> – 4) is a perfect square.

```
bool isFibonacci(int n) 
{ 
    // n is Fibinacci if one of 5*n*n + 4 or 5*n*n - 4 or both 
    // is a perferct square 
    return isPerfectSquare(5*n*n + 4) || 
           isPerfectSquare(5*n*n - 4); 
}
```

Comment: (how) can `isPerfectSquare` be implemented in constant time?

Comment: @harold `return round(sqrt(n))^2 == n;`

Comment: @harold or something like `return isInteger(sqrt(n))`

Comment: @DIBits But that ain't constant time. It is `sqrt(n)`.